# WSO2 Integration Studio v6.5.0's built-in Kafka template throws NoClassDefFoundError

Tags: apache-kafka, wso2, wso2-esb

I've installed WSO2 Integration Studio version 6.5.0 in my Windows workstation and created a project using the Kafka Consumer and Producer built-in template.

Then I configured the project with my own Kafka server settings (topic name "myTopic").

I then right-clicked the composite application and chose Export Project Artifacts and Run.

The Console window displayed at the very top the following messages:

```
[2019-06-25 09:23:45,499] [micro-integrator]  INFO - LibraryArtifactDeployer Synapse Library named '{org.wso2.carbon.connector}kafkaTransport' has been deployed from file : C:\IntegrationStudio\runtime\microesb\tmp\carbonapps\-1234\1561465425230TestCompositeApplication_1.0.0.car\kafkaTransport-connector_2.0.6\kafkaTransport-connector-2.0.6.zip
[2019-06-25 09:23:45,517] [micro-integrator]  INFO - SynapseImportFactory Successfully created Synapse Import: kafkaTransport
[2019-06-25 09:23:45,533] [micro-integrator] ERROR - ClassMediatorFactory 
Error in instantiating class : 
org.wso2.carbon.connector.KafkaProduceConnector
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/kafka/common/header/Headers
    at java.lang.Class.getDeclaredConstructors0(Native Method)
    at java.lang.Class.privateGetDeclaredConstructors(Class.java:2671)
    at java.lang.Class.getConstructor0(Class.java:3075)

[snipped rest for clarity]
```

I've tried uninstalling Integrator Studio and running it with elevated right to no avail.

I expected the project to be deployed normally.

EDIT: after copying:

- kafka_2.11-2.2.1.jar
- metrics-core-2.2.0.jar
- zkclient-0.11.jar
- kafka-clients-2.2.1.jar
- scala-library-2.11.12.jar
- zookeeper-3.4.13.jar

to the `EI_HOME/lib` directory, the exception changed to:

```
org.apache.axis2.deployment.DeploymentException: kafka/consumer/ConsumerTimeoutException
    at org.apache.synapse.deployers.AbstractSynapseArtifactDeployer.deploy(AbstractSynapseArtifactDeployer.java:219)
    at org.wso2.carbon.application.deployer.synapse.SynapseAppDeployer.deployArtifactType(SynapseAppDeployer.java:1099)
    at org.wso2.carbon.application.deployer.synapse.SynapseAppDeployer.deployArtifacts(SynapseAppDeployer.java:114)
    at org.wso2.carbon.application.deployer.internal.ApplicationManager.deployCarbonApp(ApplicationManager.java:272)
    at org.wso2.carbon.application.deployer.CappAxis2Deployer.deploy(CappAxis2Deployer.java:72)
    at org.apache.axis2.deployment.repository.util.DeploymentFileData.deploy(DeploymentFileData.java:136)
    at org.apache.axis2.deployment.DeploymentEngine.doDeploy(DeploymentEngine.java:807)
    at org.apache.axis2.deployment.repository.util.WSInfoList.update(WSInfoList.java:144)
[snipped for clarity]

Caused by: org.apache.axis2.deployment.DeploymentException: kafka/consumer/ConsumerTimeoutException
    at org.apache.synapse.deployers.AbstractSynapseArtifactDeployer.deploy(AbstractSynapseArtifactDeployer.java:207)
    ... 87 more
Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: kafka/consumer/ConsumerTimeoutException
    at org.wso2.carbon.inbound.endpoint.protocol.kafka.KAFKAPollingConsumer.startsMessageListener(KAFKAPollingConsumer.java:90)
    at org.wso2.carbon.inbound.endpoint.protocol.kafka.KAFKAProcessor.init(KAFKAProcessor.java:96)
    at org.apache.synapse.inbound.InboundEndpoint.init(InboundEndpoint.java:79)
    at org.apache.synapse.deployers.InboundEndpointDeployer.deploySynapseArtifact(InboundEndpointDeployer.java:57)
    at org.apache.synapse.deployers.AbstractSynapseArtifactDeployer.deploy(AbstractSynapseArtifactDeployer.java:197)
    ... 87 more
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: kafka.consumer.ConsumerTimeoutException cannot be found by synapse-core_2.1.7.wso2v111
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.BundleLoader.findClassInternal(BundleLoader.java:475)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.BundleLoader.findClass(BundleLoader.java:421)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.BundleLoader.findClass(BundleLoader.java:412)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.baseadaptor.DefaultClassLoader.loadClass(DefaultClassLoader.java:107)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357)
    ... 92 more
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you copied the required jars from kafka_home/libs folder to EI_home/lib, if yes then share your code to get the issue detail

Comment: Hello, thank you for your answer. I've copied the required jar files to `EI_HOME/lib`, and the exception changed a little bit. Now it says: `java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: kafka.consumer.ConsumerTimeoutException cannot be found by synapse-core_2.1.7.wso2v111`.

Comment: use kafka 2.12 and it will work that version worked for me as well,,  going forward 2.11 is not compatible you can check the available compabilities [here](https://github.com/wso2-extensions/esb-connector-kafka/blob/2.0.6/README.md)

Answer (score 1):

According to this documentation https://docs.wso2.com/display/EI650/Kafka+Inbound+Protocol, the recommended versions for Kafka is kafka_2.9.2-0.8.1.1. You can download it in the below link. http://kafka.apache.org/downloads.html. Please use those jars and copy them to the EI_HOME/lib. There is an github issue for this as well. https://github.com/wso2/product-ei/issues/2239

Comment: I too tried same kafka built in sample i am also facing the same issue. Please help me to proceed further. I followed the documentation Steps only. My kafka version 2.9.2-0.8.1.1 copied all needed jars into <EI_Home>\lib

Comment: Can you try out this custom inbound endpoint https://github.com/wso2-extensions/esb-inbound-kafka/blob/master/docs/config.md

Comment: I have tried that sample with EI 6.5 & EI 6.6. In both instances I am facing following issue ```org.apache.synapse.SynapseException: Inbound Endpoint name cannot be null```

Comment: This error comes up when the name attribute is not present in the inbound endpoint configuration. Can you recheck?

Comment: hi,now i am trying same ```kafka inbound endpoint with micro integrator 1.1.0``` in ```integration studio``` but error only coming.I have followed the mentioned step  [https://ei.docs.wso2.com/en/latest/micro-integrator/use-cases/examples/inbound_endpoint_examples/inbound-endpoint-kafka/] only

Comment: ```Class org.wso2.carbon.inbound.kafka.KafkaMessageConsumer not found. Please check the required class is added to the classpath. java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.wso2.carbon.inbound.kafka.KafkaMessageConsumer cannot be found by synapse-core_2.1.7.wso2v133```

Comment: The documentation link is broken it seems. Can you share it again it?

Comment: https://ei.docs.wso2.com/en/latest/micro-integrator/use-cases/examples/inbound_endpoint_examples/inbound-endpoint-kafka/

Comment: My usecase is Need to consume Kafka objects and push those objects into S3 bucket. Is it possible with wso2 ei 6.6.0 or MI 1.1.0? If yes please guide me to proceed further. I have lot of confusion with setup also.

Comment: Did you add all the jar files needed into the lib folder? https://ei.docs.wso2.com/en/latest/micro-integrator/setup/feature_configs/configuring-kafka/

Comment: I tried out the documentation you have shared, and it seems to be working. If you add all the relevant jars to the lib and dropin folder, the usecase should work definitely.

Comment: I have added all the jars to lib and inbound jar to dropins. I have followed same steps of the documentation i am facing issues what should i do now? If possible could you please share the steps what you did.

Comment: I did the same steps as mentioned in the documentation. 1. Created a sequence in Integration Studio 2. Created an inbound endpoint using Integration Studio. (Make sure to give Inbound Endpoint Creation Type as Custom). 3. Exported the CAPP file to Micro Integrator. 4. Copied the jars to lib and inbound endpoint to dropins. Finally I started the server. 5. I sent messages from Kafka producer script and received them in Micro Integrator.

Comment: Same steps only i had followed. Just i have one doubt i have mi1.1.0 binary setup also, now where i have to put jars and inbound endpoint? to mi1.1.0 binary lib and dropins or else integrator studio\runtime\microesb\dropins,lib ? please clear my doubt

Comment: I am trying to consume kafka objects from another server(not from my localhost). Is it possible to consume from another server? If yes means what should i use in inbound endpoint parameters section bootstrap.server or zookeeper.connect. Please confirm me.

Answer (score 0):

I may be a bit too late but we have been using Custom inbound endpoint for Kafka. We also faced exactly same issue and that was the only way to fix it.
You could use https://github.com/wso2-extensions/esb-inbound-kafka/blob/master/docs/config.md to configure it.